# How to store my data?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashmap, key

I am currently looking for a way in which I can store my data, and quickly look it up.

What currently seem to be the best idea is to use a hash map.

reasons:

- To identify what item I am looking for, one need to extract a certain set of features from the data, which can be used as a key to extract the item.

Problem here is that the features could contain noise, making the key <-> item match not 100% perfect.

In such case I need to find the key which matches the features set the best?
Or a set of features sets that matches the feature set the best. 
But how do i do that?

The feature vector is 512 long.

sorting would be a possibility? but how should I sort such a matrix?

And given the complications I am facing, is using a hash map the correct choice or is something better?

Comment: Which language are you using?